# Remove rows out-of-memory in arrow

Tags: r, apache-arrow

Suppose I have a huge dataset that does not fit into memory.
How can I delete rows in an arrow without loading the dataset into memory, and update the already changed dataset on disk.

```
library(arrow)
path <- "C:\\Users\\....\\Desktop\\my_data"
write_dataset(dataset = iris, path = path,partitioning = "Species")
arr <- open_dataset(sources = path)
```

..

```
remove_rows <- sample(1:nrow(arr), 50)

#  Not work )
arr <- arr[!remove_rows,]

# Rewrite/update arr on disk
# ...
```

Comment: I believe that parquet files are write-once, meaning once written they are immutable. If you need to permanently remove rows from it, you need to load it all into memory if doing it in R. I believe (without experience) that the python and c++ interfaces allow for sequential write of a still-open descriptor, so it is likely possible to write (in python/c++) a utility that, given clear indicators (row numbers or conditions) will rewrite data into a new file in batches, therefore not requiring all-in-memory.

Comment: I may give up parquet in favor of another format if it helps.

Comment: Maybe there is a way to do this through duckdb?

Comment: I'll revise my statement a little: if you look at the source for (say) `write_parquet`, you'll see that it calls `ParquetFileWriter` which looks like it can be used for batched writes. Paired with another open connection (to read a parquet file in batches, perhaps using `ParquetFileReader`), it seems likely to be able to support the rewriting you are going for.

Comment: It may be possible through duckdb's interface for basic read/write of a parquet file, I don't have enough experience to know for certain.